# Remove all records with opposite sign

Tags: sql, oracle, linq

I'm looking for a SQL query (or even better a LINQ query) to remove people who have cancelled their leave, i.e. remove all records with the same NAME and same START and END and the DAYS_TAKEN values differ only in the sign.

How to get from this

```
NAME    |DAYS_TAKEN |START      |END        |UNIQUE_LEAVE_ID    
--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
Alice   |  2        | 1 June    | 3 June    | 1 --remove because cancelled
Alice   | -2        | 1 June    | 3 June    | 2 --cancelled
Alice   |  3        | 5 June    | 8 June    | 3 --keep
Bob     | 10        | 4 June    | 14 June   | 4 --keep
Charles | 12        | 2 June    | 14 June   | 5 --remove because cancelled
Charles | -12       | 2 June    | 14 June   | 6 --cancelled
David   | 5         | 3 June    | 8 June    | 7 --keep
```

To this?

```
NAME    |DAYS_TAKEN |START      |END        |UNIQUE_LEAVE_ID    
--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
Alice   |  3        | 5 June    | 8 June    | 3 --keep
Bob     | 10        | 4 June    | 14 June   | 4 --keep
David   | 5         | 3 June    | 8 June    | 7 --keep
```

What I've tried

Query1 to find all the cancelled records (not sure if this is correct)

```
SELECT L1.UNIQUE_LEAVE_ID 
FROM LEAVE L1 
INNER JOIN LEAVE L2 ON L2.DAYS_TAKEN > 0 AND ABS(L1.DAYS_TAKEN) = L2.DAYS_TAKEN AND L1.NAME= L2.NAME AND L1.START = L2.START AND L1.END = L2.END
WHERE L1.DAYS_TAKEN < 0
```

Then I use Query1 twice in an inner select like so

```
SELECT L.* FROM LEAVE L WHERE 
L.UNIQUE_LEAVE_ID NOT IN (Query1)
AND L.UNIQUE_LEAVE_ID NOT IN (Query1)
```

Is there a way to use the inner query only once?

(It's an Oracle database, being called from .NET/C#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT NAME, START, END  
FROM LEAVE
GROUP BY NAME, START, END
HAVING SUM(DAYS_TAKEN) = 0
```

in order to get `NAME, START, END` groups that have been cancelled (assuming `DAYS_TAKEN` of the cancellation record negates the days of the initial record).

**Output:**

```
NAME    |START      |END        
--------|-----------|----------
Alice   | 1 June    | 3 June
Charles | 2 June    | 14 June
```

Using the above query as a derived table you can get records not being related to 'cancelled' groups:

```
SELECT L1.NAME, L1.DAYS_TAKEN, L1.START, L1.END, L1.UNIQUE_LEAVE_ID  
FROM LEAVE L1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT NAME, START, END  
  FROM LEAVE
  GROUP BY NAME, START, END
  HAVING SUM(DAYS_TAKEN) = 0
) L2 ON L1.NAME = L2.NAME AND L1.START = L2.START AND L1.END = L2.END
WHERE L2.NAME IS NULL
```

**Output:**

```
NAME    |DAYS_TAKEN |START      |END        |UNIQUE_LEAVE_ID    
--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
Alice   | 3         | 5 June    | 8 June    | 3 
Bob     | 10        | 4 June    | 14 June   | 4 
David   | 5         | 3 June    | 8 June    | 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select l.*
from leave l
where not exists (select 1
                  from leave l2
                  where l2.name = l.name and l2.start = l.start and
                        l2.end = l.name and l2.days_taken = - l.days_taken
                 );
```

This query can take advantage of an index on `leave(name, start, end, days_taken)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation with [SUM() OVER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions182.htm#SQLRF06115):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT l.*, SUM (days_taken) OVER (PARTITION BY name, "START", "END", ABS (days_taken) ORDER BY NULL) s
          FROM leave l) x
 WHERE s <> 0
```

And if you have Oracle 12, this give you the canceled:

```
SELECT l.*
  FROM leave l,
       LATERAL (SELECT days_taken
                  FROM leave l2
                 WHERE l2.name = l.name 
                   AND l2."START" = l."START" 
                   AND l2."END" = l."END" 
                   AND l2.days_taken = -l.days_taken) x
```

and this what should remain:

```
SELECT l.*
  FROM leave l
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT days_taken
                      FROM leave l2
                     WHERE l2.name = l.name 
                       AND l2."START" = l."START" 
                       AND l2."END" = l."END" 
                       AND l2.days_taken = -l.days_taken) x
 WHERE x.days_taken IS NULL
```

And something about the column names.Using reserved word in Oracle SQL is not recommended, but if you must do it, use '"' like here.

Answer (score 0):

I used Giorgos answer to come up with this Linq solution. This solution also considers people who cancel / apply their leave multiple times. See Alice and Edgar below.

Sample data

```
  int id = 0;
  List<Leave> allLeave = new List<Leave>()
  {
    new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++, Name="Alice", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,1), End=new DateTime(2016,6,3), Taken=-2 },
    new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++,Name="Alice", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,1), End=new DateTime(2016,6,3), Taken=2 },
    new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++, Name="Alice", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,1), End=new DateTime(2016,6,3), Taken=2 },
    new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++,Name="Alice", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,3), End=new DateTime(2016,6,5), Taken=3 },

    new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++,Name="Bob", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,4), End=new DateTime(2016,6,14), Taken=10 },

    new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++,Name="Charles", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,2), End=new DateTime(2016,6,14), Taken=12 },
    new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++,Name="Charles", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,2), End=new DateTime(2016,6,14), Taken=-12 },

    new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++,Name="David", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,3), End=new DateTime(2016,6,8), Taken=5 },

            new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++,Name="Edgar", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,3), End=new DateTime(2016,6,8), Taken=5 },
    new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++,Name="Edgar", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,3), End=new DateTime(2016,6,8), Taken=5 },
    new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++,Name="Edgar", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,3), End=new DateTime(2016,6,8), Taken=5 },
    new Leave() { UniqueLeaveID=id++,Name="Edgar", Start=new DateTime(2016,6,3), End=new DateTime(2016,6,8), Taken=5 }

  };
```

Linq Query (watch out for Oracle version 11 vs 12)

```
 var filteredLeave = allLeave
 .GroupBy(a => new { a.Name, a.Start, a.End })
 .Select(a => new { Group = a.OrderByDescending(b=>b.Taken), Count = a.Count() })
 .Where(a => a.Count % 2 != 0)
 .Select(a => a.Group.First());
```

"OrderByDescending" ensures only positive days taken are returned.

Oracle SQL

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    L1.NAME, L1.START, L1.END, MAX(TAKEN) AS TAKEN, COUNT(*) AS CNT
    FROM LEAVE L1
    GROUP BY L1.NAME, L1.START, L1.END
) L2
WHERE MOD(L2.CNT,2)<>0 -- replace MOD with % for Microsoft SQL
```

The condition "WHERE MOD(L2.CNT,2)<>0" (or in Linq "a.Count % 2 != 0") only returns people who applied once or odd number of times (e.g. apply - cancel - apply). But people who apply - cancel - apply - cancel are filtered out.